# SSH tunneling through a busybox router

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ssh-tunneling, busybox

I have a busybox router and I'm able to login to the console using telnet & I also have access to the web interface.

My question is, how can I create an ssh tunnel from my local network through the router so that I may be able to access my computer remotely? I'm looking for a command line based solution & I'm also aware of the fact that routers have low memory and very limited set of utilities. But although it's a minimal linux system having only a small subset of tools, but they do have utilities like route, iptables, etc. so I think may be it's possible.

Also my knowledge of busybox system is quite low so if I'm wrong somewhere, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Have you already looked at the web interface if you can configure port forwarding there?

Comment: @jofel I'v successfully port forwarded via the web interface and now I'm able to access my ssh server remotely but I'm still curious if there's a manual, hardcore way of doing it via the cmdline.

Answer (score 3):

### I have drawn some sketches

The machine, where the ssh tunnel command is typed is called **»your host«**.

[image: ssh tunnel starting from local]

---

[image: ssh tunnel starting from remote]

### Introduction

1. local: `-L Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.`

   `ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost` machine.
2. remote: `-R Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.`

   `ssh -R sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **remote** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from your local machine.

### Your example

#### Home computer runs linux

This is image number three of my sketches. Is your home computer running linux? And you have a remotehost somewhere in the internet which has ssh on it and you can simply access it from your home computer using

```
ssh remotehost
```

Then you surely have ssh installed and you don’t even need the router to create your tunnel. Use the following command on your computer (the blue box called `yourhost` represents your home computer):

```
ssh -R 11111:localhost:22 remotehost
```

Now if you are sitting at the remotehost and want to connect to your home computer via ssh, use this command

```
ssh -p 11111 homeuser@localhost
```

which will start a ssh connection to the green port `11111` on your remotehost, which is forwarded through the ssh tunnel (which even passes your busybox router) and connect to the pink port `22` of your home computer’s localhost (which is your home computer itself).

#### Of course busybox can also establish the tunnel

This is image number 4 of my sketches. You are now sitting at (or logged into) the busybox. So `yourhost` is the busybox router.

```
ssh -R 11111:nearhost:22 remotehost
```

Now when you are at the remotehost, you type again

```
ssh -p 11111 busyboxuser@localhost
```

to connect to the green port `11111` which is then forwarded through the tunnel to the busybox, and from there it is connected to the pink port `22` of the nearhost (representing your home computer).

Answer (score 2):

`ssh -L` is what you're looking for.

Lets draw a picture that has 4 total hosts, A, B, X, Y.

- A is the machine that has your regular client, lets say, web browswer
- B is your nearest local SSH capable machine, which might be the same as A.
- X is your remote SSH capable machine
- Y is the machine hosting the service (lets say, web server) you wish to access from A. Y can be the same host as X.

On B:

```
ssh -Nn -L 8080:Y:80 username@X
```

This establishes a tunnel:

```
B:8080 <--- encrypted over ssh ---> X < ---- unencrypted ----> Y:80
```

Then A can connect to B:8080 and see Y:80:

```
A <--- unencrypted ---> B:8080 <--- encrypted over ssh ---> X < ---- unencrypted ----> Y:80
```

If A is the same machine as X, and B is the same machine as Y, then the unencrypted legs never actually go over a real network; your web browser connects to localhost:8080 (tunnel start); the ssh server on X connects to localhost:80.